# Did I just discover a paradox with lns of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

[image]

Did I make a mistake on this, or is this a paradox?

Comment: Your power series for $\ln(1+x)$ is wrong. $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}n.$$ You have $n!$ in the denominator and an extra $-1$ and you start at $n=0.$ Also, this power series only works for $|x|<1.$

Comment: At the point you found yourself asserting $\ln(1+x)=e^{-x}$, you "should have" realized that something was amiss. (I say that as someone who, as a youth, once built an elaborate theory around a concept without recognizing a fatal division-by-zero error in its earliest stages. :)

Comment: $\ln(x+1)$ and $e^{-x}$ are not equal.

Comment: In particular, for positive real $x,$ $\ln(1+x)$ is increasing, and $e^{-x}$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a mistake. The expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{x^n(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

Comment: Don't start a correct with "Yes." It is confusing. Start with "You made a mistake." Or "Your mistake is..."

Comment: Exactly, especially if you read the title and then see "yes,..."

Comment: Mycomment should have been "Don't start a **correction** with..."

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew something was wrong when I saw e^x!